# URL to a Map that is created with MapFile in MapServer?

Tags: django, google-maps, mapping, geodjango, mapserver

I have installed MapServer, I have followed the whole introduction on MapServer site, I have created a Map file for a shapefile that I want to show, BUT: HOW DO I FIND URL WHERE MY MAP IS BEING SHOWN? I have watched some tutorials, but no one explains how to open web page where a map defined in mapfile is being shown. Could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: how this is related  to google maps ???'

Comment: Which web server have you got installed and on which operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Mapserver is a web cgi program so it depends on a web server like Apache or IIS to pass a request to it and return the result to the browser.  If you are using a Windows computer, you may want to look at MS4W, a nice packaging of Mapserver and a web server (Apache).